# Can we extract coordinates of current selected text in pdf using VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

Hi i am able to open a pdf document and select a specified text from the pdf document, but i want to know location of the selected text in the pdf document like page number and line number of that text.

Is there a function in vba excel which can help me get the location of the selected text in any form be it x,y coordinates or page and line number.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use send keys option of vba for this. So whenever your file open then it's, also open pdf file. And once pdf file open then it will open find option by send keys code and serach, find, copy and paste according to your sendkeys code requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am already aware of sendkey method and i am actually using sendkey option to select a text in a pdf document, but i need an index to that location so i can put in my report that the text belongs to this document page 12 line 34 or something like  this.